# Keep track of inactive sockets using select

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

I am using select to recieve messages from multiple connected clients.

```
select(fdmax + 1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

But I'd like to kick clients that didn't send anything for certain amount of time.

Tried using setsockopt function but that only works when I actively wait on blocking recv() call.

Comment: Pass a timeout to select.

Comment: That doesn't really work when I have one client that just keeps spamming and other client just sits silently there, I think

Comment: You will have to track the time of last message for each connection in some connection structure and check this periodically closing connections where this timestamp grows too old.

Comment: Okay, so what I thought. Create a checking thread to check on all connections, right.

Comment: @sushionfork That's one possibility, but of course you do not necessarily _need_ a separate thread for that.

Comment: I am new to this. How else can I check that in a single thread?

Comment: @sushionthefork i.e. pass a select timeout of 1 second and check the connection structures each time right after `select()` returns